# guess number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program is such that the user selects a number in his mind and does not input it into the computer. (Number in range(1,99))

The program guesses and prints a number. randint(1,99)
The printed number creates three modes: 
1-  is it larger than the number you have in mind when you type the letter ’s' into the program saying that the number in your mind is smaller than the number printed and the program has to guess and display another number (It should be noted that in this case, by typing ’s’ in the program, one has to guess a smaller number than his previous guess to finish the program sooner.)

2-or the printed number is smaller than the number you have in mind when you type the letter ‘l' into the program saying that the number in your mind is larger than the number printed and the program has to guess and display another number (It should be noted that in this case, by typing 'l', the program must guess a larger number than its predecessor in order to finish the program sooner.)

3=or is the printed number the same number that you had in mind and by typing the letter 'd' into the program you guess right and the program ends.

i try this

```
from random import randint
guess=randint(1,99)
print(guess)
my_answer=''
while my_answer != 'd':
    my_answer=input()
    if my_answer=="l":
        n=randint(guess,99)
        print(n)

    elif my_aswer=='s':
        m=randint(1,guess)
        print(m)
    else:
        print('done')
```

But I don't know how that doesn't guess from the previous numbers again and make the range guess smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `guess` instead of using new variable `n`. You can also set the range of the guesses every time

```
low = 1
high = 99
guess = randint(low, high)
print(guess)
my_answer = ''
while my_answer != 'd':
    my_answer = input()
    if my_answer == "l":
        low = guess
        guess = randint(guess, high)
        print(guess)

    elif my_answer == 's':
        high = guess
        guess = randint(low, guess)
        print(guess)
    else:
        print('done')
```

Example output

```
20
l
81
s
63
s
22
l
47
l
60
s
48
l
59
s
57
s
56
s
53
d
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion

```
from tkinter import *
import random
ran=random.randint(1,100)
print(ran)
i=3
while i != 0:
 
 input_number=int(input())
 if input_number==ran:
  i=1
  print("you are win")
  break
 elif (input_number-ran)>0:
   print("greater")
   i-=1
   if i==0:
    print("Game over")
    break 
   print(f"left chance:{i}")
 elif (input_number-ran)<0:
   print("lower") 
   i-=1
   if i==0:
    print("Game over")
    break 
   print(f"left chance:{i}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).